# Could Halley's method iteration be better than Newton's in some cases?

Tags: performance, precision, division, numerical-methods

I am investigating, which division algorithm will be most efficient on high-precision number inputs. One of the factors (at least with iterative methods) is choosing the best possible starting point. However, even more important could be the choice of method itself.

When trying to compute the reciprocal of a number, a, one of the methods used is the Newton iteration

[image]

This has quadratic convergence. However, a closely related Halley iteration

[image]

has cubic convergence, but a greater computational cost. Is it possible that in high precision applications, Halley's method would be superior to Newton's, despite its greater computational cost? Or maybe a combination of the two methods would be even better - starting with Newton to get some amount of precision fast and continuing with Halley...

Comment: Can you share more details? How is this related to programming?

Comment: `y=a*x, x = x*(3-(3-y)*y)` has 3 long multiplications. So with 6 long multiplications you can do either 3 Newton steps or 2 Halley steps. The combined error power 8 of Newton loses with a small margin to the combined error power 9 of Halley.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann That could probably be turned into a bit more rigorous answer...?

Comment: Probably, but not here, as the question is off-topic. This question could be on-topic on math.SE, the general difference between secant, Newton and Halley and their Ostrowski index could be discussed on scicomp.SE. But use the search function, such a topic might already exist. I know I have contributed to similar ones.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744346/is-2-the-maximum-order-of-convergence, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043066/order-of-convergence-of-a-two-step-iteration. In-between I learned that the Illinois variant of regula-falsi has the same index as the Halley method, a cubic error reduction for 3 function evaluations. Brent's method has, under optimal circumstances, an index of about 1.8. Per the first link, this might be increased for the cost of a much greater organizational overhead. Note that Dekker is already difficult in the details, Brent nearly incomprehensible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be posted on math.stackexchange, instead.